# Testing functions printing behavior

Tags: python

I have a function foo(..) which prints a lot of messages using 'print'. I want to write unit test to test correctness of printed messages. How can I get printed messages instead of printing it in console.

For example

```
def foo(x):
    print("Value is ", x)

assertEqual(OUTPUT(foo(5)), "Value is 5")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mock `sys.stdout` as found in the examples of [`unittest.mock.patch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch):

```
from io import StringIO
from unittest.mock import patch

def foo():
    print('Something')

@patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=StringIO)
def test(mock_stdout):
    foo()
    assert mock_stdout.getvalue() == 'Something\n'

test()
```

Comment: Looks perfect. Let me test that

Comment: Working. Thanks for help.