# How do I test python logging string formatting

Tags: python, exception, logging

we have had several cases where we had some string formatting issues in our logging code (i.e. something like logging.debug('%d', 'Hi there'), but obviously not this trivial) and I would like to automatically find such cases in our automated tests. But how do I do that?

The easiest way I could come up with was to get logging to raise Exceptions (that will fail the test) for such cases. But how do I do that? Python logging never raises exceptions, even if `logging.raiseExceptions` is `True`. They are printed to stderr, but nobody sees that in automated tests.

Regards,
Thomas

Comment: `logging.debug("%d" % ("some",))` did raise an exception for me
`TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str`

Comment: You can write unit tests with mocked `sys.stderr`. See a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432256/testing-functions-printing-behavior/42432352#42432352

Comment: why dont you use `logging.debug("{}".format("some"))`. I think this might be of some help.

Comment: @elena That is, because %d expects a number, not a string. The question should be corrected to read `logging.debug('%s', 'Hi there')`.

Comment: @elena: Yes, but that does the string formatting *before* going into logging, i.e. always, even when logging for that level is disabled. This is not really good style.

Comment: @Martin: No, the question should not be corrected! This is exactly the kind of bug I want to find using tests. Currently the error will be swallowed by the logging framework (and printed to stderr where it will not be seen in automated tests)